# tsql - CONTAINS searching for a single ampersand word

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, contains

When I do the following full text search using CONTAINS it does not return the expected record...

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM [group]
WHERE CONTAINS([group_title], '"Illustration*" AND "&*" AND "Commercial*" & "Art*"');
```

I've seen examples from other posts of SQL like this...

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM [group]
WHERE CONTAINS([group_title], '"Illustration & Commercial" AND "Art"');
```

That works fine since the full-text index has STOPLIST OFF but I would like each word to be separate. Is there any way to write the first query such that the & character is escaped.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean escaped? You really want to find all records containing single & character in addition to other terms? Notice, in the first query you have 2 & chars. Should the second one be changed to `AND`?

Comment: This is used as part of a user search query. So say the full search term is "Illustration & Commercial Art". I want the CONTAINS to search for a title with the word "Illustration", the literal word "&", the word "Commerical" and the word "Art".It should also match plurals i.e. "Illustrations" which is why the wildcard character is added after every word.

Comment: [Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql) about the mighty abilities of `CONTAINS` and `CONTAINSTABLE`. Furthermore you can use various independant `CONTAINS` and connect them with `AND / OR` (as always in a `WHERE` clause).

Comment: I've read the documentation, it states the following..

_{ AND | & }
Indicates that the two contains search conditions must be met for a match. The ampersand symbol (&) may be used instead of the AND keyword to represent the AND operator._

My question is how can I escape "&" so that it will search for the literal word "&".

I've tried the following but it didn't work...

`CONTAINS([group].group_title, '"Illustration*"')
    AND CONTAINS([group].group_title, '"&*"')
    AND CONTAINS([group].group_title, '"Commercial*"')
    AND CONTAINS([group].group_title, '"Art*"')`

Comment: Now I've understood and have closed this es a duplicate. Good Luck